# PHP Copy files between servers using FTP

Tags: php, ftp

This question might seem like a repeat but no solution found on SO or google worked, so I restating my issue:
I have a file on server A, located in a subfolder of the root folder, eg, 'wordpress' is the subfolder, the original file is, say, 'some_file.php - *is tagged with 0644 properties if that has anything to do...* - and would need to have the same file copied at the root of SERVER B (using the same name for simplification...)
I understood that there might be 2 solutions:
Solution 1 is 2-fold:
 1. downloading from Server A to $local_file (ftp_get...?);
 2. Uploading from $local_file to Server B (ftp_put...?),

Solution 2 (?) direct  ftp_put from Server A (where script is run...) to Server B

Neither seem to work for me, with the following  (FTP connect & login credentials are OK, and connection tested ...)

- Solution 1 :
a) Download from server A:

```
$local_file="some_file.php";
$remote_file="wordress/some_file.php";
ftp_get( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY );
```

b) Upload back from local folder to Server B:

```
$local_file="some_file.php";
$remote_file="some_file.php";
ftp_put($connect_it,$remote_file,$local_file,FTP_BINARY);
```

SOLUTION 2:

```
$local_file="wordpress/some_file.php";
$remote_file="some_file.php";
ftp_put($connect_it,$remote_file,$local_file,FTP_BINARY);
```

What am I not understanding / doing wrong ?
Many thanks for reading me through...
JMB

Comment: When you say they don't work - do you get errors (if they are enabled), what happens?

Comment: If you run the script on "Server A", why would you download the file from the Server A, if it is actually the local machine?

Answer (score -1):

Hello @JMB Please follow the [link](https://shellcreeper.com/move-files-server-to-server-using-simple-php/) its work for us and also please give file permission 664 to 777

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable. Please explain in your answer as links could expire.